# Hibernate not doing lazy loading for Parent / Children relationship. Instead, it does 2 SQL loads on query

Tags: hibernate

I have a Parent / Children relationship like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Agent", schema = "dbo", catalog = "MyTime")
public class Agent implements Serializable {
    private Set<AgentAttr> attributes = new HashSet<AgentAttr>();

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="Agent_GUID")
    public Set<AgentAttr> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(Set<AgentAttr> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}
```

This DAO call is to perform the query on Agent.

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("from Agent where userName = :userName");
query.setParameter("userName", userName);
List list = query.list();
```

The query returns the Agent object with the attributes collection loaded in each element of the list.
When inspecting the Hibernate logs, it shows that it performs 2 SQL queries, one to load the Agent,
the 2nd one to load the attributes.

I didn't expect this at all since the Hibernate document says the lazy loading is the default behavior.
I would expect that the attributes returned by the query is null.  And then Hibernate only loads it when Agent.getAttributes() is called.
That's the whole point of lazy loading, i.e. loads it only when needed, right?  I also tried explicitly putting     @OneToMany( fetch=FetchType.LAZY ) there,
but still the same, doesn't do the lazy loading.

Appreciate any pointer on what I may have done wrong.  Thanks.

Here's the Hibernate Log:

```
2014/08/28 16:21:14.487 [DEBUG] <http-bio-8080-exec-3> (SqlStatementLogger.logStatement:109) - 
    /* 
from
    Agent 
where
    userName = :userName */ select
        agent0_.Agent_GUID as Agent_GU1_1_,
        agent0_.Address_Email as Address_2_1_,
        agent0_.Address_SIP as Address_3_1_,
        agent0_.Address_TEL as Address_4_1_,
        agent0_.Address_XMPP as Address_5_1_,
        agent0_.Company_GUID as Company_6_1_,
        agent0_.Create_Tstamp as Create_T7_1_,
        agent0_.Create_User as Create_U8_1_,
        agent0_.Enabled as Enabled9_1_,
        agent0_.First_Name as First_N10_1_,
        agent0_.Last_Name as Last_Na11_1_,
        agent0_.Location as Locatio12_1_,
        agent0_.Password as Passwor13_1_,
        agent0_.Role as Role14_1_,
        agent0_.Security_Ans as Securit15_1_,
        agent0_.Security_Q as Securit16_1_,
        agent0_.Update_Tstamp as Update_17_1_,
        agent0_.Update_User as Update_18_1_,
        agent0_.User_Name as User_Na19_1_,
        agent0_.Work_Status as Work_St20_1_ 
    from
        MyTime.dbo.Agent agent0_ 
    where
        agent0_.User_Name=?
2014/08/28 16:21:14.487 [TRACE] <http-bio-8080-exec-3> (BasicBinder.bind:81) - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [achansv@contactsolutions.com]
2014/08/28 16:21:14.794 [TRACE] <http-bio-8080-exec-3> (BasicExtractor.extract:78) - extracted value ([Agent_GU1_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [9E5537A6-96FF-4656-9F75-70B58E44C0E9]
2014/08/28 16:21:20.632 [DEBUG] <http-bio-8080-exec-3> (SqlStatementLogger.logStatement:109) - 
    /* 
from
    AgentAttr 
where
    agentGuid = :agentGuid */ select
        agentattr0_.Agent_Attr_GUID as Agent_At1_4_,
        agentattr0_.Agent_GUID as Agent_GU2_4_,
        agentattr0_.Attr_Category as Attr_Cat3_4_,
        agentattr0_.Attr_Name as Attr_Nam4_4_,
        agentattr0_.Attr_Value as Attr_Val5_4_,
        agentattr0_.Create_Tstamp as Create_T6_4_,
        agentattr0_.Create_User as Create_U7_4_,
        agentattr0_.Enabled as Enabled8_4_,
        agentattr0_.Location as Location9_4_,
        agentattr0_.Update_Tstamp as Update_10_4_,
        agentattr0_.Update_User as Update_11_4_ 
    from
        MyTime.dbo.Agent_Attr agentattr0_ 
    where
        agentattr0_.Agent_GUID=?
2014/08/28 16:21:20.632 [TRACE] <http-bio-8080-exec-3> (BasicBinder.bind:81) - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [9E5537A6-96FF-4656-9F75-70B58E44C0E9]
```

Comment: how do you check that the AgentAttrs are loaded?

Comment: I set a break point on the query and check each Agent element in the returned list.  I check the attributes collection and see it loaded with values from the DB.

Comment: if the Collection is lazy loaded then the type of Collection itself should be something like ProxyCollection. Once you touch this proxy collection it will initialize the elements with the "real" objects from the database. It might be that then you touch the collection in the debugger, hibernate inits the collection. Do you see the second SQL query just after fetching the parent object?

Comment: I see.  But as you said, in the Hibernate log, I see that the 2 SQL statements are called one right after the other, that's why I suspect it's loaded at the same time.  Here's the log for your inspection:

Comment: Umm... The Hibernate log is too long to be pasted in the comment.  I update the question above.

Answer (score 0):

According to the spec found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html):

The LAZY strategy is a **hint** to the persistence provider runtime that data should be fetched lazily when it is first accessed. The implementation **is permitted to eagerly fetch** data for which the LAZY strategy hint has been specified.

Comment: However, here's what it says in the Hibernate Reference Doc:

20.1.1. Working with lazy associations
By default, Hibernate uses lazy select fetching for collections and lazy proxy fetching for single-valued associations. These defaults make sense for most associations in the majority of applications.

Comment: that does not contradict with the spec, right? It's still remains lazy loading, and for some complex object hibernate will load them lazily

Comment: Ok, I guess what I'm saying is that if Hibernate is doing lazy loading, then how come I see the children's value all loaded right after the query.  I would expect only to see the values when Agent.getAttributes() are called.  Also, the Hibernate log shows that it loads both the parent & children from the DB at the same time with 2 SQL statements executed one right after the other.  I guess the question is how do we know lazy loading is working.